# OpenGL / GLSL varying not interpolated across GL_QUAD

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am using GLSL to render a basic cube (made from `GL_QUADS` surfaces). I would like to pass the `gl_Vertex` content from the vertex into the fragment shader. Everything works, if I am using `gl_FrontColor` (vertex shader) and `gl_Color` (fragment shader) for this, but it doesn't work, when using a plain `varying` (see code & image below). It appears the varying is not interpolated across the surface for some reason. Any idea what could cause this in OpenGL ?

`glShadeModel` is set to `GL_SMOOTH` - I can't think of anything else that could cause this effect right now.

**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 120

varying vec4 frontSideValue;

void main() {
   frontSideValue = gl_Vertex;
   gl_Position = transformPos;
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 120

varying vec4 frontSideValue;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = frontSideValue;
}
```

[image: Left: Unwanted result, Right: Proper interpolation]

Comment: what is the size of the cube? probably it is larger that 1? use 0...up to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result looks just like you are not using values in the range [0,1] for the color vector. You basically use the untransformed vertex position, which might be well outside this range. Your cube seems centered around the origin, so you are seeing the small transition where the values are actually in the range [0,1] as that unsharp band.

With the builin `gl_FrontColor`, the value seems to get clamped before the interpolation.

Comment: The poster could check this diagnosis using `frontSideValue = clamp(gl_Vertex, 0.0, 1.0);` but it sounds right to me.

Comment: You must be right - I thought I was drawing a unit cube, but it was actually 10 units long in each direction from the origin. Thanks!